# WPF MVVM Why use ContentControl + DataTemplate Views rather than straight XAML Window Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, architecture

**Why This?**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Have your ExampleView.xaml set up as:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MVVMProject.ViewModels">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:ExampleVM}" >
        <Grid>
            <ActualContent/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And create the window like this:

```
public partial class App : Application {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {

        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
        ExampleVM context = new ExampleVM();
        app.DataContext = context;
        app.Show();
    }
}
```

---

**When it can be done like this?**

App.xaml: (Set startup window/View)

```
<Application x:Class="MVVMProject.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="ExampleView.xaml">
</Application>
```

ExampleView.xaml: (a Window not a ResourceDictionary)

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMProject.ExampleView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MVVMProject.ViewModels">
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:ExampleVM />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ActualContent/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Essentially it's **"View as DataTemplate" (VaD) vs. "View as Window" (VaW)**

Here is my understanding of the comparison:

- VaD: Lets you switch Views without closing the window. (This is not desirable for my project)
- VaD: VM knows absolutely nothing about the View, whereas in VaW it (only) has to be able to instantiate it when opening another window
- VaW: I can actually see my xaml rendered in the Designer (I can't
  with VaD, at least in my current setup)
- VaW: Works intuitively with
  opening and closing windows; each window has (is) a corresponding View
  (and ViewModel)
- VaD: ViewModel can pass along initial window width, height, resizability etc. through properties (whereas in VaW they are directly set in the Window)
- VaW: Can set FocusManager.FocusedElement (not sure how in VaD)
- VaW: Less files, since my window types (e.g. Ribbon, Dialog) are incorporated into their Views

---

So what's going on here?  Can't I just build my windows in XAML, access their data cleanly through properties of the VM, and be done with it? The code-behind is the same (virtually nil).

I'm struggling to understand why I should shuffle all the View stuff into a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Think like this: ViewModels shall be displayed either in Windows or UserControls. Poco's shall be displayed in DataTemplates. :)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

People use `DataTemplates` that way when they want to dynamically switch Views depending on the ViewModel:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
          <!-- View 1 Here -->
       </DataTemplate>

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
          <!-- View 2 here -->
       </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>

</Window>
```

So,

if `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `VM1`, then `View1` will be displayed,

and if

`Window.DataContext` is an instance of `VM2`, then `View2` will be displayed.

Granted, it makes no sense at all if only 1 View is expected, and never changed.

Answer (score 8):

Since in VaD the view models know nothing about the views, you can build a fully functioning application entirely made up of view models only and no views. This leads to the possibility of writing an application that can be driven entirely by code. This in turn leads to the possibility of performing integration testing without the GUI. Integration testing through the GUI is notoriously fragile - while testing through view models should be more robust.

Answer (score 5):

From my personal experience:
Both work models are aviables, depending of what you want, and depending of the application requirements. The idea behind `VaD` is decopling the content, and the container. If you implement `VaD` you can use this template (by default) when ever you show any item of this type. You can use it in `ItemsControls` (lists, listviews, grids, etc) and in `ContentControls` only making bindings. Like you said, `VaD` works for switching the window's content with out closing and opening a new. Also you can define the view using `UserControls`, then you take control if focused elements, and also you can manage code behind. So, your data template may be like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MVVMProject.ViewModels">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:ExampleVM}" >
    <CustomUserControl A="{Binding A}" B="{Binding B}" DataContext="{Binding}" .../>
</DataTemplate>
```

You also in an `UserControl` may set dependency properties, thats make easier the job, because allow bindings and decoupling the app.

But of course, if you app doesn't require dynamically content switching, it is fine to use `VaW` for the main window, or any other window. In fact, you can use both `VaW` and `VaD`. This last one can be used for inner items in the app, that doesn't require windows. You shoose what is better for you, depending of application requirements, and the time aviable for developing the app.
Hope this personal experience helps...