# Why would you use DataTemplate in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

could someone please explain to me what is the difference if I use
`DataTemplate` inside the `ListView` in XAML?

I have used `ListView` to display the content from my `ObservableCollection` without using `DataTemplate` and with `DataTemplate` it seems to look exactly the same?

Why then would I want to use Data Template? I would like to see a simple explanation/example.

Comment: Can you show a code how you use DataTemplate in XAML? How you imagine to put image with text as list item?

Comment: So, the difference is that in Data Template I can put not just text but any content and from my Properties and decide what it looks like?

Comment: Right. Data templates allow you to do *anything*, not just a simple text block

Comment: Please take a look at examples in the internet, blogs, tutorials, MSDN. You can for example put a *panel* (let's say Grid for example) and add many things as children to this *panel*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTemplate is used to show data in ways beyond a simple text block. Sure doing this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Doesn't buy you much. But it allows you to do stuff like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Caption}"/>
     </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Which is pretty cool! You can put *anything* inside the template, so it makes `ItemsControl` (and its derivatives) some of the most powerful classes in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at #HighCore's answer here [WPF MVVM Why use ContentControl + DataTemplate Views rather than straight XAML Window Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864891/wpf-mvvm-why-use-contentcontrol-datatemplate-views-rather-than-straight-xaml-w).

```
 <Window x:Class="MyViews.MainWindow"   
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel" 
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Title="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="{Binding Height, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}" Left="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" Top="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">


<Window.Resources>     
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:OtherViewModel1}">            
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Text}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:OtherViewModel2}">
        <view:ConnectivityLED />
    </DataTemplate>      
</Window.Resources>
```

So you can see Mainwindow is talking to more than 1 viewmodel, Main is its own view model which is its datacontext and it also has reference to otherviewmodel1 and otherviewmodel2. Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to know about data templates in *collection* controls.