# WPF How to make (lets say) one master Window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to develop an multipage WPF application. I tried to achieve that by using one Window and multiple Pages. When I need to switch from one to another page I just change Content of main `Window` to point to that page. I have filling that I'm using wrong scenario because I don't have idea how to reuse XAML code for example an `Menu` controll, `StatusBar` and `ToolBar` for all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **ContentControl**. It changes view based on ViewModel. Place your static elements in one place and in changeable area a *ContenControl* object.
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864891/wpf-mvvm-why-use-contentcontrol-datatemplate-views-rather-than-straight-xaml-w) and [here](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/).

Answer (score 0):

One idea is you have a `PageViewModelBase` that implement a base `virtual Property and Methods` for Menu and StatusBar model and ... Then Each PageViewModel `Override` proper implementation of PageViewModelBase, Then Window contains Menu or StatusBar that **Bind to DataContext of Pages**.