# Associating a ViewModel to a View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a main View and corresponding ViewModel. Because the main View is too complicated so I split it into many small Views; and each small View also has its own ViewModel.

My question is that how to "associating a sub ViewModel to a sub View" in the main View?

I am doing the following way, not sure if it is right or I have to use DataTemplate?

```
<StackPanel>
     <local:SmallView-A DataContext="{x:Type local:SmallViewModel-A}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <local:SmallView-B DataContext="{x:Type local:SmallViewModel-B}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <local:SmallView-C DataContext="{x:Type local:SmallViewModel-C}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You can split main View into multiple UserControls.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864891/wpf-mvvm-why-use-contentcontrol-datatemplate-views-rather-than-straight-xaml-w?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: It depends on how your main view model is structured and how you're intending to use your SmallViews. If there is for instance a SmallViewModel property in your main view model, you could directly bind a SmallView's DataContext, lile `<local:SmallViewA DataContext="{Binding SmallViewModelA}"/>`. However, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Instead of *EDIT: Sorry typo* just fix your XAML.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for pointing it out. I fixed the typos.

Comment: `DataContext="{x:Type local:SmallViewModel-A}"` doesn't seem to make much sense. As already said, a view's DataContext might be bound to a property of a main view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to use the following code likely.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewInstance}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type vm:MyViewModel">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would saif that the right anwser is the following :-)... (not tested!)

1. in a generic.xaml, associated views and viewmodels
2. In your MainViewModel create properties for each sub viewmodel
3. In your MainView, bind content presenter to there properties

   ### generic

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SubViewModel1}">
       <Views:SubView1 />
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SubViewModel2}">
       <Views:SubView2 />
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

   ### MainViewModel

   ```
   public SubViewModel1 Sub1 { get; set; }
   public SubViewModel2 Sub2 { get; set; }
   ```

   ### MainView

   ```
   <Grid>
       ## your layout here 
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Sub1}" />
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Sub2}" />

       ##could be
       <TabControl ItemSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}" />

   </Grid>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

In your 'Views' folder(Create one if you have not got one already) create a new user control called `SmallViewA'.

In your main XAML:

```
xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:[Your app name].Views"

<views:SmallViewA x:Name = "vSmallViewA" Loaded = "SmallViewALoaded"/>

private void SmallViewALoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vSmallViewA.DataContext = YoursmallAViewModelshouldgohere;
    // Initialise
}
```

Add your `SmallViewA` control the the `SmallViewA` control in the Views folder. From there you can bind your properties from your `SmallViewA` Viewmodel.

Follow the same procedure above for `SmallViewB` and `SmallViewC`

Note: be sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your ViewModel.

Comment: Could you comment why you have downvoted? So I can improve or delete my answer?

Comment: I don't think that the question is about how to do it, it's about which is better, this is probably why your answer got downvoted; still the downvoter should've added an explanation

Comment: You should probably explain how this is supposed to work at all, i.e. how the view's code behind should get access to the respective view model instance. In other words, where is `YoursmallAViewModelshouldgohere` supposed to come from?